# Slide list items off screen and loop back in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate logos on the bottom of a site. I want them to disappear of the left side of the screen and then loop around and reappear on the right side of the screen. Similar to a ticker but without the dead white space at the end. I can make it almost work in jsfiddle (except it tweaks out when I adjust the screen size) and it doesn't work in my actual project at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/yoda_wookie/jm7w0jf8/1/

```
$(function(){
    var scroller = $('#logo-ticker div.footer-logo-slider');
    var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
    scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
    var curX = 0;
    scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('left', curX);
        curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
    });
    var fullW = curX / 2;
    var viewportW = scroller.width();

    // Scrolling speed management
    var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:2};
    var $controller = $(controller);
    var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
    {
        if (duration === undefined)
            duration = 600;
        $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
    };

    // Pause on hover
    scroller.hover(function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(0);
    }, function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });

    // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
    var doScroll = function()
    {
        var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
        var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
        if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
            newX -= fullW;
        scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
    };
    setInterval(doScroll, 20);
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

I'm still learning jQuery and really struggling with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: your fiddle doesn't contain rendered HTML rather it has `php` statements within it. can you put together a jsFiddle with pure HTML rendered content so we can try and see what the problem is? At the moment it is a little difficult to debug, at least for me.

Comment: Sorry. I changed a bunch of stuff but didn't update. Hopefully this is better: http://jsfiddle.net/yoda_wookie/jm7w0jf8/1/